# RMagick / ImageMagick no primitives defined

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I just installed ImageMagick and RMagick on my system so I can learn how to use it for a project. Following along with one of the examples in the [docs](https://rmagick.github.io/usage.html#drawing_on), I call `circle = Magick::Draw.new`, which returns an error: `(no primitives defined)`.

Can anyone give me an explanation of what this error means and how I can fix it?

In an IRB session, here are the exact steps I took:

```
require 'RMagick'

canvas = Magick::ImageList.new
canvas.new_image(250, 250, Magick::HatchFill.new('white', 'gray90'))

circle = Magick::Draw.new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added any drawing primitives to your circle object. If you want to draw a circle you have to add a circle primitive and specify the center of the circle and a point on its perimeter. Optionally you can also specify primitives for the stroke (border) and fill colors, the stroke width, etc.

circle.circle(125, 125, 25, 125)

The Draw class is quite well documented. See [here](https://rmagick.github.io/usage.html#drawing_on) for a little tutorial, and [here](https://rmagick.github.io/draw.html#draw) for the list of drawing primitives and more examples.

Comment: That makes sense! I saw the message and assumed it was an error meaning that one of the dependencies was missing. Thanks!